# Free LOPSA Memberships

Tags: discussion

**Opt-In is now closed. Thanks everyone, We will let the lucky 40 sysadmins know shortly**

---

I'm very happy this has gone over so well, with 50 people opting in. If you didn't get a membership this time keep contributing as this won't be the last time or way we give back to the people that make this (and all Stack Exchange sites) so great!

---

We are sponsoring 40 of our top users with memberships to LOPSA. If you are not already a LOPSA member and are interested in a membership, please answer this question. Voting doesn’t matter, but if you want to say something about why you are interested in this membership, please feel free.

We will keep this question open for a week. At the end of the week, we will sort the users who answered this question by rep earned this calender year and take the top 40. We will then take the emails associated with your account and pass them on to LOPSA (So make sure you have an accurate email in your profile).

For more information about LOPSA and why we are doing this, see [this blog post](http://blog.serverfault.com/post/free-lopsa-memberships-for-top-server-fault-users/).

Comment: I don't rank high enough to qualify anyway but seeing as I've already dropped my membership to SAGE-AU due to its total ineffectiveness I can't see how a LOPSA membership could be of benefit to anyone over here.

Comment: @John: Unless I'm misunderstanding the criteria, it looks like you're #36 for the calendar year 2011.

Comment: John: Most local groups are only as good as their members/participants make them.

Comment: @Miles, You're right. I stupidly counted 5 across instead of 4.

Comment: @Kyle, given that I would qualify but am not interested will that membership simply become void or will it flow down to the next person in rank? I'd personally prefer to see the flow down option to maximise any possible benefits to either LOPSA or SF members.

Comment: How does oner see his rank for the year?

Comment: @Raphink, I simply went to the users page, clicked on "year" and (mis)counted how far down I am.

Comment: @John thanks. I guess I didn't realize that I haven't been that active this year ;-)

Comment: @John, it will be top 40 that answered this question sorted by this years rep. Since people might already have memberships or may not be interested, I made this question so it could be on an opt-in basis. That is why I converted your answer to a comment.

Comment: Will we be fighting the evil brotherhood of PEBKAS? :)

Answer (score 6):

Is it only for U.S residents (the examples in the post only mention U.S locations)? If not, I'm interested.

Comment: Hi @Raphink, good question. They currently have about 50 non-US members. There are some non-US chapters listed in https://lopsa.org/localprogram . So you don't have to be in the US, in fact starting a chapter in France would be awesome ;-) !

Comment: Thanks for the info @Kyle.

Answer (score 2):

For you non-US folks, LOPSA has a strong online virtual community; there is much more to LOPSA than the locals.  The locals are a great place to meet your fellow sysadmins in person, but you can also meet them online in #lopsa on Freenode (irc.lopsa.org).

And...  you might even discover (online) that there are enough sysadmins near you to start your own LOPSA local!

Answer (score 2):

For everyone who is asking questions here about LOPSA, you'll find (most) answers at the main LOPSA site, LOPSA.org.

To recap:

1. International - small but growing contingent outside the US
2. Online community (mailing lists (https://lopsa.org/mailinglists), IRC (https://lopsa.org/irc), personal blogs at LOPSA.org (https://lopsa.org/blog)
3. RSS feed of over 40 LOPSA member blogs, most focused on sysadmin
4. If you want to find or help form a local chapter, contact LOPSA Board (https://lopsa.org/localprogram)
5. Open to all "administrators": all OSes, DBs, storage, network, security, web, etc.

For LOPSA members, remember that voting for the Board begins NEXT WEEK!

Answer (score 1):

I'd love a free membership. Yay!

Answer (score 1):

Yes please.  I don't really have much to say, but I'm always looking for ways to become better...

Answer (score 1):

I've been meaning to join LOPSA for a while - this is a good excuse to force myself to do it :)

Answer (score 1):

Throwing my hat in to the ring, count me in on this one.

Answer (score 1):

I'd love a membership. Thanks Kyle, this is a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be interested in a membership. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to throw my Windows NT server into the mix.  ;)

Comment: ...wouldn't you prefer to throw it into the FIRE? :-p

Comment: I would if I had the money to replace the software running on it...

Answer (score 1):

Chalk me up; looked into this a while ago.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds cool. I'd be interested.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in for this, please please please. And I'm in Boston on the Orange Line, so the Back Bay is remarkably convenient for me.

Comment: June 8th @MIT is the next talk, hope to see you there :-) http://www.bblisa.org/

Comment: These meetings have been in my calendar for so long and I've never made it to one. I should try to change that. It's the curse of living in a great city - all the things you never do because "I can do that anytime" and then never do ....

Answer (score 1):

I'm interested in membership too. Although my local (European) chapter in [Dublin](http://sysadmin.ie/) doesn't seem very active.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be interested in joining. Canada ho!

Answer (score 1):

I'd love a membership!    Yeeeeeeeaaaawweeeee!

Answer (score 1):

I am interested in joining.. Not sure I'll make the cut since i'm not an active suer

Answer (score 1):

If this helps me learn and get exposed to more - count me in

Answer (score 1):

I would (also) love a membership. I'm from Belgium but I don't think that should be a problem :).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Count me also in for the membership

Answer (score 1):

I'd be happy to join the community.

Though there appear to be not affiliate groups close by (York, UK - Ireland is closest but that is a fair journey from here by rail) and I'm not in possession of enough time to set one up so I'd be happy for others who could contribute more actively to be considered far ahead of me.

Comment: You could fly from Leeds for <£40 return if they had a suitably timed meetings.

Comment: That might be more practical (depending on the train+bus links from here, as I'm not road-safe myself). Train+ferry travel from York to Dublin isn't expensive compared to other UK rail prices (~£70 return), it just takes 8 or 9 hours so a day-trip is at least three days away.

Answer (score 1):

Curious what the community is like for LOPSA? Is it mostly mail lists, or....? What's all involved?

Comment: LOPSA has mailing lists, a fairly frequented IRC channel or two, monthly online meetings, and gatherings at various conferences. There are local chapters/affiliates, and could easily be more with enough localized interest.

Comment: Well, I'll throw my hat in the ring, if for nothing else than try the mailing lists. See what it's like. Especially if it's educational and another resource to turn to when looking for information and assistance!

Comment: If they have educational posters I'm sold :-)

Comment: What kind of educational posters would you like to see? We're always looking for new ideas! Drop me a line - standalone.sysadmin@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

I'm interested. Thanks for pulling this together for us.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I'm #122 for the calendar year, but who am I to say that all 121 of my superiors will be interested? I'll throw my name into the ring.

Answer (score 1):

I love the dialog box that pops up now: Did I read through the more than 30 answers this question already has?  I sure did, and my answer is going to be the same as most of the others:

I'd like a membership if I qualify.

Answer (score 0):

Interested if I still qualify.

Answer (score 0):

yes please, i'd like to get in.

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested! Here in Buenos Aires we don't really have a very active Sysadmin community, so I was looking forward to something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds interesting and I'd fit the criteria... but I don't really know how useful could it be from Italy.

Answer (score 0):

I'd love join. Please count me in.

Answer (score 0):

I would be interested if I am eligible.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for doing this. Please add me to the list of hopefuls.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds awesome. I'm interested.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in it to win it.  Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

I'll put my name into the hat as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to take a look at the [LOPSA Chapters and Affiliates](https://lopsa.org/localprogram);  There might be one in your area!

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to put my name in the fishbowl, also.

Count me in! 8-)

Answer (score 0):

Hi SF and Lopsa,

Would be grateful if I can be a Lopsa member (I am a Non-US Resident).

Please count me in :-)
Kind Regards
Rihatum

Answer (score 0):

I would like to be part of it!

Answer (score 0):

Count me in if I'm elegible :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes I'm interested. Another international here, currently hailing from Turkey.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be up for it, if I make the grade.

Answer (score 0):

I don't rank high enough but I'd certainly be up for it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be interested too if I qualify.

Answer (score 0):

I am interested in a membership.  Sounds like a hot ticket.

Answer (score 0):

I'm definitely interested. Count me in.

Answer (score 0):

I am definitely interested in becoming a member and contributing any way I can.

Answer (score 0):

I rather doubt that I'll have enough rep to make the cut, but I'd certainly be interested.

Answer (score 0):

Count me in, if I have enough rep.

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested in this, would love to get a UK branch organised.