# Did the free LOPSA memberships ever get sent out?

Tags: discussion

From my calculation I was one of the top 40 for the year that posted on the thread, but have heard nothing.
It's entirely possible that I calculated it wrong, but thought I'd check.

Comment: You're top-40 across the entire site, so I don't think much calculation is needed to figure out you'd be top-40 in the LOPSA draw ;)

Comment: @Mark Well unfortunately if you base it on just this years numbers (which I think is what they were doing), then I drop down to 50 (I blame the new job), but I'm pretty sure there were at least 10 people ahead of me who weren't in it.

Comment: @Zypher took this over when I left for a conference. I believe we needed a couple of the winner's real names -- then we will send the list over to LOPSA. So the list should go to LOPSA this week, then it will be on their timeline.

Comment: Might I request that the list of those who (a) made the grade and (b) opted-in via the meta thread is posted somewhere, so that those of us who aren't expecting to hear from LOPSA can stop worrying about this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure how to raise this, but I have still heard nothing from LOPSA, and by my calculation it's about a month since they had our details.  I don't want to open a new question for this, unless that's the right thing to do, but could anyone whose name appears above and **has** heard from LOPSA leave a comment to that effect?  If no-one has heard yet, I can sit down and shut up; but if others have heard, and I have not, then I'll need to dig a bit further.

**Edit**: thanks for that, Zypher, but it's now nigh on a month later, again, and I for one have still heard nothing.  Has anyone else heard?

Comment: We're looking into it for you!

Comment: This is the latest http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1526892#1526892

Comment: Many thanks for the update; sorry both for slightly nagging, and slightly pointless nagging (being an idiot, I missed that someone else - who has even had the courtesy to since remove their answer - had added a fresh answer to bump this up, and got a comparable answer - shortly before I did).

Answer (score 3):

The usernames who made the list are:

```
Bart Silverstrim
Cakemox
Caleb
DanBig
David Spillett
Dennis Williamson
DisplayName
dmourati
dyasny
Eduardo Ivanec
ErikA
Evan Anderson
ewwhite
GregD
hmontoliu
Holocryptic
Hyppy
Iain
JamesRyan
Jason Berg
Javier
Jim B
joeqwerty
John Gardeniers
Julien Vehent
MadHatter
mfinni
Mike
MikeyB
Miles Erickson
pepoluan
Sam
SLY
sybreon
TiZon
voretaq7
Ward
Warner
```

As well as the following, but we need their real names:

```
gravyface
shadowman12
Chadddada
```

Comment: better add someone else to that list, as I have no use for the membership. Thanks all the same.

Answer (score 2):

Posting to bump this topic. What's the status of these LOPSA memberships?

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1526892#1526892  This was the last I heard, but I've yet to get anything from LOPSA...

Answer (score 2):

Just a little update from me:

I got the email today, signed up and have my account up and running :-).

```
Hi,

As a top user of Server Fault,  LOPSA welcomes you to the League of
Professional System Administrator (LOPSA) community.  LOPSA is a
non-profit whose mission is to advance the practice of system
administration; to support, recognize, educate, and encourage its
practitioners; and to serve the public through education and outreach
on system administration issues.  LOPSA offers:

- a great mentor/protege program if you need a bit of help
  with a large project (https://lopsa.org/mentor)
- IRC chat rooms (irc.lopsa.org#lopsa) and mail lists (see
  https://lopsa.org/mailinglists) where you can get help and hang out
  virtually with other system admins
- chapters in Seattle, NYC, NJ, Boston, Baltimore, East
  Tennessee, Pittsburgh, and Los Angeles where you can meet system
  admins face to face and hear about the latest technologies.  See
  https://lopsa.org/localprogram for a contact list.
- member discounts (https://lopsa.org/MemberDiscounts) on
  technical products and on insurance (https://lopsa.org/ProInsurance).

We look forward to hearing from you.
```

Comment: Mine landed a short while ago too. Thanks !

Comment: Ditto mine, ditto thanks!

Comment: I got mine. Thanks, ServerFault! (maybe someone could post a pointer [here](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1558/free-lopsa-memberships) to this question)

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact that I had previously made it perfectly clear that I was not interested in a LOPSA membership and repeated that in my comment to Kyle's post here I have just received my notice from LOPSA.

What a waste. That's a membership that will not be used, despite numerous others having asked for one. I don't understand why this situation has been allowed to occur.

Answer (score 0):

I spoke with the person who'd be handling this on LinkedIn in early July when i tried to join the LOPSA group. His note was:

"I still haven't seen the final list of memberships from ServerFault, and I'm the one who will be importing them (I'm the volunteer currently managing the membership system). 
If you resubmit your request to join the group, I will go ahead and approve it when it comes in."